# Prevent auto reloading the page after an await call execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor-webassembly

I am new in Blazor and working with an WASM where my controller likes below : -

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
 public async Task<bool> UpdatePerson(int id, [FromBody] ElementType Object)
 {
     await _eTypeService.Update(id, Object);
     return true;
 }
```

and, Edit razor component html likes below : -

```
@page "/elementtype/edit/{id}"
@inject HttpClient Http
@using OrderManagement.BLL.Models;
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager navigation
@inject IJSRuntime js

<h2>Edit</h2>
<h4>Eelement Type</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind="@elementType.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" @onclick="@(async () => await UpdateElementType())" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" @onclick="@cancel" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   </div>

@code {

[Parameter]
public string id { get; set; }

ElementType elementType = new ElementType();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    elementType = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ElementType>("api/ElementType/" + Convert.ToInt32(id));
}

async Task UpdateElementType()
{
    var response = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ElementType/" + id, @elementType);
    // for getting response from POST call
    bool eTypeResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<bool>().Result;
    if (eTypeResponse)
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Updated Successfully!");
        navigation.NavigateTo("elementtype");
    }
    else
    {
       await js.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Error occurs to save data!");
    }
}

  void cancel()
  {
    navigation.NavigateTo("/elementtype");

  }
}
```

Here, I am facing problem that when execute the code for the update: -

```
var response = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("api/ElementType/" + id, @elementType);
```

It automatically reloads the Edit page and staying that page with updated data. Not going to the next line where I want to catch the update response and do some custom operations (Showing messages & redirect to page at List view).

Comment: Blazor sometime have strange behaviors when debugging and there is an error. I think you don't need the ".Result;" when using await